# NuxtJS prefetch Data when visiting route with Nuxt-Link?

Tags: javascript, nuxtjs

I have this setup:

index.vue -> containing different `<NuxtLink :to="/abc">` or `<NuxtLink :to="/def">`

abc.vue and def.vue with the function `async asyncData() { ... }` to server-side load data from an API.

My problem is, that the function `asyncData` is only executed server-side when requesting the path `/abc` or `/def` for the first time. Thanks to the documentation of NuxtJS i know that this is the normal behavour. But how do i get the data from the API prefetched on the server when using `<Nuxt-Link>`?

Answer (score 1):

Well you need to do a workaround. `asyncData` provides an argument the `context`. So you can access your vuex store:

```
asyncData({store}) {
   store.commit("somecommit", "somevar");
}
```

In your vuex store you have a state somewhere for example `link1`.

With your commit you change that state.

Now you can go with `<NuxtLink :to="$store.state.link1">`

Comment: Is this resolving the issue that asyncData is executed on the client when clicking on the `<NuxtLink :to="/something">` and the data is not fetched?